# Installing Qt 5.5 on Windows 7

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2015

I would like to install latest version of Qt (5.5) on Windows 7 for C/C++ application development, and have a few questions:

1. Can I use Microsoft "Visual Studio Community" edition (2015) as the compiler?
2. I assume I need to install Visual studio first and then Qt?
3. I am going to install Qt from [here](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/), after downloading and installation do I need to build Qt? Or it is ready to go?

Is there a tutorial that explains all the required steps in details. I have done Google search and found bits and pieces here and there not not a good complete step-by-step reference. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: 1. Yes
2. No
3. No, it's ready to go.

Comment: I recommend using the Qt IDE, though. It's really nice.

Comment: If 2 is no, how qt finds proper compiler?

Comment: You can configure Qt after installing it. `configure.bat -platform win32-msvc2010` or something similar.

Comment: Debugging Qt applications outside of the Qt editor is a real nightmare, though. I can't recommend the Qt editor enough. You can run unit tests quite easily, debug, see resource utilization, etc.

Comment: Does Visual Studio community edition install a compiler or I need to install a compiler myself?

Comment: So are you saying I don't need to install Microsoft visual Studio community edition?

Comment: @TJ1 - unless you already need VS for something else, I'd recommend against that load of bloat. GCC FTW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the compiler, which is integrated in visual studio. I don't think you can get the newer ones without Visual Studio (From official sources). However, you can use Qt on windows without msvc. You can build with the minGw compiler - but I personally like msvc more.

Regarding VS2015: It won't work without extra configuration. Qt 5.5 supports msvc2013 only (the next release, 5.6, will support the msvc2015 compiler). But Visual Studio 2013 will work. The order of installation doesn't matter.

After you installed Qt, all you need to do is launch Qt-Creator and start coding ;) If you wan't to use Visual Studio instead, there is a Plugin on the bottom of the download page ("Other downloads"). Visual Studio 2015 isn't supported here too, but 2013 is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In QT how should I set it up to use the VS2015 compiler?

Comment: Well you will need to build Qt yourself - and this can be very complicated (Depending on what you need and how much you now about Qt). You have to change make-specifications etc ... If you really want to try it, search for it. But I would recommend you to use 2013 instead - at least until the end of the year, since thats the planned release for Qt 5.6.

Comment: On Microsoft website I can only download VS2015, how can I get 2013 version?

Comment: there it is: https://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2013-community-vs .Right below the first passage